# I don't have questions, I have answers

Tags: discussion

The reputation requirement to clean up wrong answers is dumb. I agree that under a certain amount your answers should be reviewed, but outright rejecting them is not smart.

If you argue that following stringent rules opposed to providing an accurate answer to a question is the way to go, you've defeated your own platform.

Comment: Firstly, this doesn’t belong here, but on Meta (which requires 5 rep points). Secondly, it’s not true as far as I can tell. Even new users with 1 rep point can suggest edits to questions and answers, which are then placed in a moderation queue where higher-rep users vote whether they should be applied or not. That’s one of the very basic tenets of the StackExchange model. And if an answer is wrong, you can always just downvote it and write a better one yourself—that’s what the site is for, and unless the question is protected, that doesn’t require any rep points either.

Comment: If you find supporting evidence for your answer, I'm sure the protection can be lifted, momentarily.  There have been three answers, two of which are deleted–you can't see these deleted answer because you need 10K rep, yikes! The deleted answers were highly offensive and really unsuitable, so blame those two idiots not the site's rules.

Comment: No, it has not been possible to post answers the last 3 questions I've had answers to. I only write on topics where I can see an incorrect answer has been upvoted, to avoid that people become ill informed. It required a reputation of 50 to comment or answer. None to edit, but the edit was declined because it was not the same answer as the one I was editing on.. No shit, it was wrong.

Answer (score 9):

The issue here is that the question you want to answer is protected. Questions are protected occasionally because we get a lot of nonsense answers, especially if the question hits the Hot Network Questions list.

In your case you want to post an answer to the [question about "Semi" trucks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76769/why-is-it-called-a-semi-truck-doesn-t-semi-mean-part). That's great! If you know something others don't, then please share it. **But,** because that question has fallen foul of untoward attention in the past, we need to make sure that people who post on it are invested in the site: we do that by ensuring that they have at least one other upvoted answer (which gives the required ten rep points).

It's not OK to edit a post to say it's wrong: that's vandalism and your suggested edits were rightly rejected.

If you would like to invest in the site, please create an answer on an unprotected question which can be upvoted. Once that's happened, you will have the required ten rep points to allow you to go back to the first question.

The "protected question" restriction isn't the only [restriction which new users encounter](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user), but it is the most obvious one which causes the most issues. Asking a question about it does allow it to be explained, which could also help others in the future.

Comment: Good answer. Also suggesting improvements to 5 other posts can get the user a 10 rep.

Comment: My issue is that correct information is treated as irrelevant. The question I edited the answer on "question about "Semi" trucks" is still incorrect. Had I been able to post an answer instead that would require peer review I would've done so.

Comment: @Kenneth Information is not treated as irrelevant, as long as it's added to the right place. Changing existing answers in the way you attempted is not how Stack Exchange sites work. I've explained here what's going on with the question you're interested in, and how to deal with those restrictions. Your answer needs to be an answer in its own right, and in this case you need to gain 10 rep before you can post that new answer.